# Why is console.log used? What does it do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I can see many place used `console.log()`. Can anyone tell me why it is used?

Something like this,

```
function createCheckBox( idsToShow ) {
    for( i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++ ) {                
       console.log( idsToShow.indexOf('main' + i + '|' ) + '  ' + 'main' + i + '|' );
       if( idsToShow != '' && idsToShow.indexOf('main' + i + '|' ) == -1 ) continue;
       checkBoxs += "<li> <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"main" +  i + "\" value=\"Example" + i + "\" name=\"lbl"+ i +"\" /> <label id=\"lbl"+ i +"\">Example" + i + "</label></li>";                                    
       ids += 'main' + i + '|'; //is the check box id.                     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It logs things to a debug console (which is built into many browsers (e.g. Chrome Developer Tools) and available as an extension (e.g. Firebug for Firefox) in many others)

Comment: I sometimes wonder... what about a browser without a console? Say Firebug isn't installed. Is `console.log` an error then?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal — yes, don't use `console.log` in production code.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems to use log, but console.info is more useful.  In Firebug it gives you the line number where it came from, so you don't have to be so descriptive in the console message.   It's also much easier to track down if a colleague leaves an errant console somewhere in your site.

Comment: check this out: if(!window.console){window.console = { log: function(){} }; no more worries about errant console messages messing up old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

`console` is a debug handler found in many browsers. For more retarded browsers you could try [FauxConsole](http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/fauxconsole/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use console.log to show you the log of every executed line and debugger; at certain line to break the execution of script, provided you are using firebug or any other developer tools.